# Error: "expected a type specifier"

Tags: c++, struct, sfml

I am getting this error and I don't know why when trying to create a new object pointer.

Here is the code for my header class

```
#ifndef CURSOR_H_INCLUDED
#define CURSOR_H_INCLUDED
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#Include "Mango.h"
#include <stack>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

struct cursor{
 Texture tCursor;
 Sprite sCursor;
 stack<Mango*> inv;
 float money;
 void Sell();
 cursor();
 ~cursor();
};

#endif CURSOR_H_INCLUDED
```

and in the main it try doing this

```
cursor * cursor = new cursor();
```

but it gives me that error.

Comment: rename your variable, so it's not called the exact same thing as your class. e.g. `cursor* c = new cursor;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've named your pointer the same name as the class name. You can't do:

```
struct Foo {int a;};

int main()
{
        Foo* Foo = new Foo(); // Because
// After here ^^^ Foo is no longer a type but a variable. And you can't "new"
// a variable. Thanks to user4581301 for teaching me this.

    return 0;
}
```

In:

```
cursor * cursor = new cursor();
         ^^^^^^
```

Change your pointer name from cursor to something else.

P.S. Interestingly thanks to user4581301 I know that variables CAN have the same name as user-defined types, but is obviously a bad idea.  So:

```
Foo Foo; // Fine
Foo.a = 7; // Fine
Foo newFooObj; // Doesn't make sense, Foo is no longer seen as a type
```

Comment: Explain why you can't do this, as in what went wrong, and you have an upvote.

Comment: @user4581301 Hmm, I would have said that variables and objects can't have the same name as types, but both Visual Studio and GCC allow struct Foo{int a;}; Foo Foo; Foo.a = 7;  and also Foo* Foo; Foo->a = 7;  So I'm still figuring it out. My compiler says it's a syntax error at Foo Foo, but only seems to happen with "new" allocation.  Answer is I don't know... yet.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually, my last comment would entail my answer is wrong, when I said "you can't name your pointer the same name as the class name"

Comment: In `Foo* Foo = new Foo();`, `Foo` is a data type until `Foo* Foo` redefines `Foo` to be a variable of type `Foo`. You cannot `new` a variable.

Comment: @user4581301 Ahh, weird. I'm glad I learned that. Let me adjust my answer